# Changing normal quotes to curly ones in php

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to change straight quotes (**"something"**) to curly quotes (**„something“**) in **PHP**. Other answers are not for my situation, since I have a product details imported from DB as **variable**, using `str_replace` I've managed to only change it to **„** and it seems like I can't change the second one to be **“**. From what I know, there is no way to accomplish this.

For example:

$description outputs -> Hello "everyone", I would like to "change" this straight "quotes" to "curly" ones.

What I would like:

$description outputs -> Hello „everyone“, I would like to „change“ this straight „quotes“ to „curly“ ones.

Comment: I may be wrong, but isn't "curly" quotes just a font style?

Comment: It is not, it can be done by specifying q {quotes: "„" "“";} in css. But we have a custom made CMS in which atleast 15 - 20k products. Imagine changing every product from straight to <q></q>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace` with the pattern `"(.*?)"`.  Then, replace with the capture group `$1` inside curly quotes.

```
$input = "Hello \"everyone\", I would like to \"change\" this straight \"quotes\" to \"curly\" ones.";
$output = preg_replace("/\"(.*?)\"/", "„$1“", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello „everyone“, I would like to „change“ this straight „quotes“ to „curly“ ones.
```

**Edit:**

You are trying to replace HTML code, where double quotes have been encoded, so try the following:

```
$input = "Exklusiv von buttinette: Baumwollstoff &quot;Leo&quot;,";
$output = preg_replace("/&quot;(.*?)&quot;/", "&ldquo;$1&rdquo;", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Exklusiv von buttinette: Baumwollstoff &ldquo;Leo&rdquo;,
```

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Maybe because straight quotes are just ", without \.

Comment: @asobak A literal double quote inside a PHP string denoted using double quotes needs to be escaped with a backslash.  My code is working against the sample data you provided in your question.

Comment: That is correct, I know that. But there shouldn't be a reason to not work. I've tried already a similar approach, but I targeted quotes insted a word..

Comment: Then give me sample data for which my answer fails.

Comment: Exklusiv von buttinette: Baumwollstoff &quot;Leo&quot;, Farbe: wei&szlig;/grau/braun aus der Quiltserie &quot;Mona&quot;, aus besonders feiner, weicher und hochveredelter Baumwolle (Renforc&eacute;), Motivgr&ouml;&szlig;e: 5 10 mm, Breite: 150 cm, Gewicht: ca. 130 g/m&sup2;.

Comment: That is copied from page source. Otherwise in CMS it's basic " and not &quot;.

Comment: You're doing this on HTML text, not the rendered output.  Try my updated answer.

Comment: I can't belive I'm that stupid. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using `explode` and `array_reduce`:

```
$str = 'Hello "everyone", I would like to "change" this straight "quotes" to "curly" ones.';

$parts = explode('"', $str); // or  explode('&quot;', $str);
$carry = array_shift($parts);

$result = array_reduce($parts, function ($c,$i) {
    static $up = false;
    return $c . ((true === $up=!$up) ? '„' : '“') . $i;
}, $carry) ;
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/hJMS1)

Obviously if your original quotes are html entities you have to change the first parameter of `explode`.

---

Using `strtok`:

```
$str = 'Hello "everyone", I would like to "change" this straight "quotes" to "curly" ones.';

$result = substr(strtok(".$str", '"'), 1);

while (false !== $part = strtok('"')) {
    $result .= "„${part}“" . strtok('"');
}
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/fcXdR)